# How to write a predicate expression on AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, predicate, aws-glue

I'm new to AWS Glue and PySpark. Below is a code sample

```
    glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "my_S3_data_set",
    table_name = "catalog_data_table",
    push_down_predicate = my_partition_predicate)
```

in the guide [Managing Partitions for ETL Output in AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions-pushdowns).

Suppose a SQL query to filter the data frame is as below

```
    select * from catalog_data_table
    where timestamp >= '2018-1-1'
```

How to do the pre-filtering on AWS Glue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925034/aws-push-down-predicate-not-working-when-reading-hive-partitions/70453286#70453286

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, your data should be partitioned and then you will be able to use these partitioning columns in `push_down_predicate` expression.

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388993/aws-glue-predicate-push-down-condition-has-no-effect/51412786#51412786) answer.